# Devops.se elevator pitch

Tags: discussion

One of the question for a new site is the elevator pitch, how would you describe this site in a few sentence if you had to introduce the site to a stranger during a 2 or 3 stages elevator trip.

For background I rephrased here text from [this meta.se post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223674/the-real-essential-questions-of-every-beta/223675#223675) 4th point.

For memory, our actual description is:

> **DevOps Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for
>   software engineers working on automated testing, continuous delivery,
>   service integration and monitoring, and building SDLC infrastructure.

I'm voluntarily omitting any question as reference or chat talks to allow fresh positions, so quote you proposition and add a paragraph or two to give some details on why this should be the site description.

However to get some actual background from the site you may follow [this search](https://devops.stackexchange.com/search?q=Devops) and get a look at comments under [this question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4/how-to-change-existing-policies-in-an-organisation) for more details about the culture side of devops.

So how would you describe devops.se in less than 30 words ?

Comment: Hell, I still don't know what DevOps is supposed to *be*, so what would a site that's about it contain (other than questions defining the term)? :P

Comment: Should I link the existing questions revolving around the word Devops to help with background ?

Comment: It would probably be useful as a way to frame answers.  My comment was a bit tongue-in-cheek, though - it's not that I'm not familiar with the field, but rather that I've seen [so many](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/814/960) definitions that it's impossible to even include them all in an elevator pitch, much less use them to describe what this site is supposed to be about.

Comment: Well, it's indeed a very hard task to summarize the subjects of Devops ;)  I'll try to complete the question latet

Comment: I'd like some skill-set description for DevOps as well. Being a tester with pretty wide automated testing experience I expected to be able to contribute. Guess what? No go. There will be more people like me. How to  activate? Better for the site...

Comment: @Bookeater I'm unsure of what you're after with this comment. Maybe you could write a Meta question about your concerns ? You'll have more room to describe them and it may be the starting point for the lengthly site description also.

Comment: @Tensibai thanks I'm hovering between just that & chat.

Comment: An additional guideline I've heard is "less than 150 characters if possible". Might be worth checking answers against that too.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to re-use the summary from [the Area 51 proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops):

> Beta Q&A site for software Engineers working on automated testing, continuous delivery, service integration and monitoring, and building SDLC infrastructure.

Comment: It's indeed the actual text (I may have shorten it up in the quote in the question) and a very valid proposition :)

Comment: Oh derp, I forgot to reread the question when I came back to this today. >_<

Comment: No worries, I had wrote it if no one did :) I'm just trying to keep a step back to let the community voice positions :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to see something more along an actual DevOps definition using all parts of (CAMS - Culture, Automation, Measurement and Sharing).

> DevOps StackExchange is a Q&A for professionals working on issues related to organizational transformation toward better work Culture, wider adoption of Automation and Measurement and Sharing of experiences for better understanding of each other both in the companies among individuals and teams and outside in the industry in conferences and forums like this one.

Comment: I'd strip it after 'Sharing of experiences' (I'm afraid this would be too long for the short description space). There'll be more space in the on-topic page (next step on the todolist for the site)

Comment: Sounds good like that.

Comment: Does it mean that DevOps applies only to companies transforming, or does it also happen in Greenfield new companies? I am also a bit reluctant to tie this site to a specific meme since these come and go much faster than the buzzword (devops) itself.

Comment: Good point there. I just tried to take it a step away from Tools Tools Tools.

Comment: And yet you didn't mention tools even once, even though it is common knowledge that DevOps has a hefty amount of tools involved ;) (like you just said)

Answer (score 3):

my 2cc

> DevOps StackExchange Q&A site for questions about practices, processes, and tools used during software development and delivery to reach improved business value.

or the other way around

> DevOps StackExchange Q&A site for questions about practices, processes, and tools used to reach improved business value by way of software development and delivery.

Answer (score 1):

> **DevOps Stack Exchange** is a Q&A site for software engineers working to increase business value by building SDLC infrastructure, and the practices, processes, and tools used during software development and delivery.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, the [best way to distinguish ourselves](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/a/229/2845) is to focus on architechure instead of specific technical problems. As such, a good elevator pitch might be:

> DevOps Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for business leaders in the technical field seeking to architect or rearchitect rapid, efficient and high-velocity software delivery systems using techniques such as automated testing, continuous integration & delivery, monitoring and related procedures, policies, processes, and software.

Comment: That's seems very very long and hard to digest at first glance...

Comment: @Tensibai - Feel free to edit for clarity and brevity if you like the concept

Comment: It's kind of late here, I'll see tomorrow with a fresh mind if I can word a more constructive comment :)