# Do all Docker-related questions belong to DevOps?

Tags: discussion

I'm relatively new to devops.stackexchange.com and I already asked a couple of Docker-related questions. But before asking, I always wonder if I should post here, on stackoverflow, on serverfault on linux&unix, or on some other stackexchange site.

The ["What to ask?" help page](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is rather helpless here.

So, I wonder if *all* Docker-related questions should belong to this site--or if there are some rule of thumb to choose the "right" stackexchange site. Unless the mods here could migrate the question in case of need?

---

FWIW, here are few border-line topics I could think about:

- *"Is Docker the right tool for XYZ"* (could be asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)
- *"I run XYZ in  Docker container, how to change the configuration"* (could be asked on https://serverfault.com/)
- *"I need to access XYZ running in a container from my app, but my code doesn't work"* (could be asked on https://stackoverflow.com/)

---

EDIT: related to https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/a/229/11179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mostly right on your analysis, no, all docker-related question doesn't belong here.

This site topic encompass questions about tools revolving around devops approach to problems, ad hoc task with docker are not really related to any devops approach or methodology.

So as usual, use your best judgement when asking :)
Feel free to ask here on meta to get advice on the question before posting it in main.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tensibai. If I understand it well, in your vision, the DevOps SE site is mostly for high-level questions regarding software architecture, organizational tasks, and methodology, rather than for technical questions. So I suppose [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/6148/11179) and [that](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/6149/11179) would be off-topic. If that's the case, could you migrate them to a more relevant SE site?

Comment: Well, as you already self answered the second, no harm done leaving it there and accepting your own answer (which sounds very good IMHO). First the first one I'm tempted to say it would be better suited to server fault or superuser, I'll check with those sites mods tomorrow.